# How to Dynamically assign Step Name at Spring Batch partitioned Step?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch Job which consists of Step A, B, and C.

Step B and C is combined into one flow, lets call it flow X.

Step A is a step manager whose job is to perform partition to execute flow X.

Now, From Spring Batch Code I understood that the built-in StepExecutionSplitter will provide unique name on each flow X execution using the name template supplied by Partitioner, e.g: X:partition0, X:partition1, X:partition2, etc.

So far so good, however since in my case flow X consists of Step B and C, Both B and C'names have to be unique as well for each flow X's execution since otherwise upon step failure we might get the wrong lastStepExecution.

Now, how can I carry over the partitionName from Step A / Flow X to step B and C and therefore produce similar naming for B and C: C:parition0, B:partition2, etc?

I have tried putting the partition name as part of the Map<String, ExecutionContext> returned by Step A partitioner and then access it in Step B and C declaration like below:

```
 @Bean
 @StepScope
 public Step stepB( @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[partitionName]}") String partitionName, Tasklet someTasklet) {
return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("stepB" + partitionName)
    .tasklet(someTasklet).build();
```

}

Apparently the above will not work due to this issue:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1335

have tried solutions in above link but to no avail.

again what I need is just a way to 'carry over' the partition naming to all slave steps names

I do think that this behavior should be the default though because we have to be able to differentiate each slave steps execution in partitioned environment

This is my config:

```
 @Bean(name = "sampleJob")
 public Job sampleJob(Step manager) {
    return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("sampleJob")
        .start(manager).build();
  }

@Bean
Public Step manager(Partitioner somePartitioner, Step mainStep){
    Return stepBuilderFactory.get("manager").partitioner(somePartitioner, mainStep.getName()).step(mainStep).build();

@Bean
public Step mainStep(Step slave1, Step slave2){
    Flow someFlow = new flowBuilder<simpleFlow>().add(slave1).next(slave2).build();
   Return stepBuilderFactory.get("mainStep").add(someFlow).build();
}

@Bean
Public Step slave1(){
   Return stepBuilderFactory.get(/* Need to correctly include the partition name also here*/)
   // Reader, processor, writer config, etc
)

@Bean
Public Step slave2(){
   Return stepBuilderFactory.get(/* Need to correctly include the partition name also here*/)
   // Reader,processor,writer config,etc
)
```

Comment: The problem with your configuration is marking a `Step` bean as step scoped. This is not correct because it tells Spring Batch to create the bean lazily until the step is started, which means do not create the step until it is started.. Your setup is not clear to me. Please share the code of your job/step flow definition to be able to help you.

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine I have added my config example  there. I understood that putting stepScope at my step declaration is not correct hence why I was looking for another way to 'carry over' partition name to my slave steps

Comment: Continuing from our discussion here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1335, My point was that since the issue is due to spring batch not being able to correctly obtain the correct last stepExecutionContext caused by duplicate step name (slave steps will have same name * the number of partition) , cant the partition handler give them unique name based on the partition number bfore executing slave steps?

Comment: Its basically similar to what the stepExecutionSplitter is doing, create unique stepExecution for each partition

Comment: `jobBuilderFactory.get("sampleJob").partitioner(..)` does this compile? There is no `partitioner` method on JobBuilder. Moreover, `stepBuilder.partitioner(somePartitioner, manager.getName()).step(manager)` is incorrect, you should pass the worker step name and worker step and not the manager (see Javadoc), something like `stepBuilder.partitioner(somePartitioner, workerStepName).step(workerStep)`. Finally regarding to `Need to correctly include the partition name also here`: you should not put the partition name here, but the step name. Those are different things.

Comment: I made a mistake as I did not have my IDE with me, the Job will execute the manager and the manager will perform the partitioning of mainStep containing slave 1 and slave2.

Comment: Exactly so the problem now is that given my configuration above Spring Batch will run my mainStep like `mainStep:partition0, mainStep:partition1, mainStep:partition2, etc` which is correct.  However all those mainStep execution will spawn slave1,slave2 instead of `slave1:partition0, slave2:partition0, etc` and so upon step failure and restart it will treat all slave1,slave2 execution as being the same while in fact `slave1:partition0 is different from slave1:partition1` for example

Comment: That is why I am thinking of modifying the step name to include the partition name, e.g: `From slave1 becoming slave1:paritition2`

Answer (score 0):

The default `SimpleStepExecutionSplitter` does not seem to fit your use case.

So you either need a custom [`PartitionNameProvider`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/PartitionNameProvider.html) or (if this does not work for you) a custom `StepExecutionSplitter`.

Comment: From My observation of the source code, it has got nothing to do with the splitter anymore. Yes, `the splitter is the one responsible for partitioning mainStep to produce stepExecutions like: mainStep:partition0, mainStep:partition1, etc.` Afterwards however `it is the responsibility of partitionHandler to execute those stepExecutions`. In other word, Splitter doesn't even know that my mainStep is a FlowStep. the default `TaskExecutorPartitionHandler` will be the one holding the actual step instance. In other word `I need a custom partitionHandler instead of custom splitter`

Comment: If I understand correctly, your question was about the default naming that does not fit your need. The naming is implemented in the splitter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/d8fc58338d3b059b67b5f777adc132d2564d7402/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/SimpleStepExecutionSplitter.java#L183-L184. That's why I tried to point you to the `PartitionNameProvider` or a custom splitter. But if you found a way to fix your issue with a custom partitionHandler, then I'm glad to hear that.

Comment: This is why in the discussion here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1335, I mentioned that I could perhaps create a custom partitionHandler which will check whether the actual step instance is a `FlowStep`. If it does, somehow `recreate the flow` to contain step with the correct partitionName. The above however is apparently not possible since there is no way I am aware of I can get the actual flow definition from flowStep instance

Comment: Yes you are correct, my problem has got to do with default naming. It is the `default naming of the slave step (slave1 instead of slave1:partition0, slave2 instead of slave2:partition3, etc)` instead of `the naming of the mainStep (mainStep1:partition0, mainStep2:partition2, etc)`. Those two are different things. Splitter will only split the naming of the mainStep, afterwards it is the responsibility of the partitionHandler to execute those thereby spawning the Slave Step

Comment: I will give you an example, with 2 partitions, my batch job will have 3 step executions initially: `manager, mainStep:partition0, and mainStep:partition1`. Afterwards `mainStep:partition0 will spawn slaveStep1, and slaveStep2, so does the mainStep:partition1`. In the end you will end up with `7 stepExecutions, 3 initial ones, 2 slaveStep for each partition.`. Now what would happen if one of my slaveStep1 fails? Upon restart, Spring Batch will look for last execution of slaveStep1 to check whether it has completed successfully and so here spring batch might not return the correct last execution

Comment: because it only see 2 slaveStep1 at the DB and so if your successful slaveStep1 happen to end `After` the failed slaveStep1, Spring batch will think that everything's fine, nothing to do